# How to annotate both citations and that something has a definition (i.e. text style)

Tags: print-design, text, typography

Say you have a sentence like this:

```
I am an \adef{example} sentence about \acite{foo.com}.
```

Where `\adef` is marking it as a definition and `\acite` is marking it as a citation. The citation would be put in the bibliography, and the definition would be defined in the glossary. But I'm wondering how typically to visually show this.

```
I am an exampleᵈ² sentence about foo.comᶜ⁹.
```

Wondering if it should be done sort of like that, or if there is a better way to tell someone that "hey this has a definition" or "hey this has a citation".

This is monochrome, so no color as well. There are also already "links" which are underlined.

Also, sometimes words might be 2 or 3 word combos, like "Open Source", so like

```
I am an exampleᵈ² sentence about open sourceᶜ⁹.
```

That doesn't quite seem right.

Answer (score 1):

This is a graphic designers site, perhaps an expert within the publishing area give a more technical answer. Are the icons allowed?

Using **Zapf Dingbat**:
[image]

Using **Wingdings 2**:
[image]

Using **Zapf Dingbat**:
[image]